# Unable to list down the Azure Resources through SDK

Tags: python, azure, sdk, azure-functions

Unable to list down the azure resources using SDK though developer id, though developer id is able to list resources through cli and portal. Same issue exists in function app deployed in portal while accessing other resources through user managed identity.

```
`import azure.functions as func
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import AzureAuthorityHosts
from azure.mgmt.containerservice import ContainerServiceClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient, SubscriptionClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, AzureAuthorityHosts
from azure.eventhub import EventHubProducerClient
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential, ChainedTokenCredential, ManagedIdentityCredential

credential = DefaultAzureCredential(logging_enable=True)
subscription_id = os.environ\["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"\]

# Obtain the management object for resources.

resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

# The expand argument includes additional properties in the output.

resource_list = resource_client.resources.list_by_resource_group(
resource_group, expand = "createdTime,changedTime")

# Show the groups in formatted output

column_width = 36
print("Resource".ljust(column_width) + "Type".ljust(column_width)
\+ "Create date".ljust(column_width) + "Change date".ljust(column_width))
print("-" \* (column_width \* 4))

for resource in list(resource_list):
print(f"{resource.name:\<{column_width}}{resource.type:\<{column_width}}"
f"{str(resource.created_time):\<{column_width}}{str(resource.changed_time):\<{column_width}}")

**Error:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\\Users\***\\Downloads\\projects\\emlocal-v1\\LocalTestonly 2.py", line 47, in \<module\>
for resource in list(resource_list):
File "C:\\Users\***\\Downloads\\projects\\emlocal-v1.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\azure\\core\\paging.py", line 132, in __next__
return next(self.\_page_iterator)
File "C:\\Users\***\\Downloads\\projects\\emlocal-v1.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\azure\\core\\paging.py", line 76, in** __next__
self.\_response = self.\_get_next(self.continuation_token)
File "C:\\Users\*\\Downloads\\projects\\emlocal-v1.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\azure\\mgmt\\resource\\resources\\v2021_04_01\\operations_operations.py", line 9102, in get_next
map_error(status_code=response.status_code, response=response, error_map=error_map)
File "C:\\Users\*\*\*\*\*\\Downloads\\projects\\emlocal-v1.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\azure\\core\\exceptions.py", line 109, in map_error
raise error
azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: (SubscriptionNotFound) The subscription 'XXXXXX_XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX' could not be found.
Code: SubscriptionNotFound
Message: The subscription 'XXXXXX_XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX' could not be found.`
```

I'm expecting display of resource groups and resources for subscription passed in env variable.

Comment: it clearly says subscription not found, so you either have a typo in your subscription id or lack permissions

Comment: i'm(developer id) able to view subscription and resources through CLI and Portal but not through sdk. I believe that ensure i have required permission to view/list subscription and resources. I'm running this is in azure gov.

Comment: that fine, but I dont think its possible to interpret this error any other way

Comment: This has been resolved after using following configuration. resource_client = ResourceManagementClient( credential=credential, subscription_id=subscription_id,  base_url=cloud_env.endpoints.resource_manager, credential_scopes=[cloud_env.endpoints.resource_manager + ".default"]

Comment: Hi @Yadhunandan if you solved your issue kindly post an answer so that it will be helpful for other members who can encounter the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able connect to subscription and resources using following code

### Obtain the management object for resources.

```
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id, base_url=cloud_env.endpoints.resource_manager,                                     credential_scopes=[                                        cloud_env.endpoints.resource_manager + ".default"])
```

### Obtain the container object for accessing cluster resources

```
container_client = ContainerServiceClient(credential, subscription_id,                                               base_url=cloud_env.endpoints.resource_manager, credential_scopes=[                                                   cloud_env.endpoints.resource_manager + ".default"])
```